# wordpress как подключить страницу home.php

Tags: wordpress

Как в wp правильно подключить страницу home.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете назначить главную страницу в админке сайта, поставить ей слаг `home`. и тогда создав шаблон или переиминова `page-home.php` в каталоге темы сайта, по правилам WP он будет иметь больший приоритет чем `index.php` и сначала отображать его, но всё зависит от вашей Темы.

Answer (score 1):

> Как в wp правильно подключить страницу home.php?

Такой страницы в ВП нет. Есть [шаблон темы](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B3.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.86.D1.8B), который подключится автоматически при его наличии.